# .NET SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize shows larger than PrimaryMonitorSize

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Working on a Winforms application the code sets the initial window state.
It is using `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize`.
Generally the program seems to function but when I look at the `SystemInformation` in the debugger I see the following:

`PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize`: **`Width` = 1696, `Height` = 1026**
`PrimaryMonitorSize`: **`Width` = 1680, `Height` = 1050**

The `PrimaryMonitorSize` is the resolution of my monitor so that makes sense.

The `PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize` height of 1026 feels correct (1050 - 1026 = 24)
24 pixels seems to be the size of the Windows task bar.

Then I unlocked and tweaked the Windows task bar to be twice as high.
Measuring with a pixel ruler it shows to be around 80 pixels.
However I now get this `PrimaryMonitorSize`: **`Width` = 1680, `Height` = 984**.
The actual window area seems to be around 970 pixels.

Somewhere .NET is getting "interesting" values that at least from a pixel perspective don't make sense.

Where are these values coming from?
And how can I make sense of these values?

Comment: Window Borders are Offscreen when maximized but still count into WindowSize.

Comment: Lies, lies, appcompat lies.  GetSystemMetrics() dates from long before Windows got a taskbar.  Particularly the fat borders a window gets on Aero were a significant appcompat problem.  Favor Screen.WorkingArea instead.

Comment: `Screen screens = Screen.AllScreens;` will return an array of all system monitors. The `screens[0].WorkingArea.Width` and `screens[0].WorkingArea.Height` will return the desktop working area resolution for the primary screen.  This area resolution is correct for the monitor orientation, and excludes any taskbars, docked windows, etc.  On multi-monitor systems, `screens[index].WorkingArea` would be used to retrieve the area information for each additional screen.

Comment: The Screen object is handy.  I'll add that to my program.  The bit from Ralf about the borders is also interesting however I'm still looking for more details on how that all factors into what I see in the SystemInformation.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this will be the best answer but I'll try to address the question.

Under the hood the [`SystemImformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation_properties(v=vs.100).aspx) is calling into at least two native API calls in user32 DLL.

- [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx)  (1)
- [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)  (2)
  *The (1) and (2) are for referencing back from the table below*

With a small helper (see the end of this answer) I obtained the following values that basically give insight in the behavior observed. In the following table I show the property, a value on my box and which native API is called and parameters supplied. For example "(1) 32" means `GetSystemMetrics` is called with 32 as parameter. Two numbers means the API is called twice.

```
| SystemInformation                 | Value                           | native api    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FrameBorderSize                   | {Width=8, Height=8}             | (1)  32 33
| PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize | {Width=1296, Height=916}        | (1)  61 62
| PrimaryMonitorSize                | {Width=1280, Height=1024}       | (1)  0  1
| WorkingArea                       | {X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=984} | (2)  48
```

`PrimaryMonitorSize` is in the indeed the size your videocard reports (the API also mentions an equivalent call will be to `GetDeviceCaps`).

As `WorkingArea` is the bounds of the screen excluding docked toolbars and **taskbar**, if you only have a taskbar you could reason that the height of my taskbar is around 1024-984 = 40 pixels.
The `PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize` is the size a window should have to cover the working area *excluding* the window borders. As the `FrameBorderSize` is 8 in both directions the width and heigth get 2 * 8 = 16 added to the `WorkingArea` size, therefore giving a size of 1296 and 916 to fit exact in my `WorkingArea`.

If I unlock my taskbar and resize it the new value for `WorkingArea:{X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=942}` shows an extra row is 42 pixels.

**How to dump properties**

```
foreach(var p in typeof(SystemInformation).GetProperties().OrderBy(n => n.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(null,null));
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But I don't understand this. You say "As the FrameBorderSize is 8 in both directions the width and heigth get 2 * 8 = 16 added to the WorkingArea size, therefore giving a size of 1296 and 916 to fit exact in my WorkingArea."... But height should be 984 + 16 = 1000, not 916.. What am I missing? Thanks